# Returning a custom status code from express-validator .isEmail()

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I have little experience with Node, and even less on Express/express-validator (been more of a NestJS guy). I'm tweaking some validations on an endpoint, and almost everything is working as it should. Currently I'm having a small issue trying to return a `400` HTTP status code when `.isEmail()` validation fails. Currently it returns the correct message, but with a (apparently default) `404`. How can I setup `.isEmail()` to return a `400` error when it fails? I've tried some workarounds with `.custom()`, but with no success. Currently the code is:

```
exports.recoverPassword = [
    check('email')
    .custom((email, { req }) => {
        return new Promise (async (resolve, reject) => {
            let noEmail = (email === null || email === undefined)
            if(noEmail) {
                req.statusCode = 400
                return reject()
            }
            return resolve();
        })
    }).withMessage('Invalid request.')
    .bail()
    .isEmail()
    .withMessage('Email must be a valid email.')
    .custom((email, {req}) => {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            let userExists = await ValidationHelper.exists(User, {email});
            if (!userExists) {
                req.statusCode = 404
                return reject()
            }
            return resolve();
        })
    }).withMessage('User not found.')
    .bail()
    .custom(async (email, {req}) => {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            let user =  await ValidationHelper.first(User, {email})

            if (!user) {
                return reject()
            }
            if(user.blocked_at !== null) {
                req.statusCode = 403
                return reject()
            }
            return resolve()
        })
    }).withMessage('User account is blocked.')
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the status code to the response not the request

```
exports.someRoute = (req, res, next) => { 
 res.statusCode = 400 
};
```